# json null error help in php

Tags: php, json, curl, google-api

I get 'json is null' as error

My php file:

```
<?php


    if (isset($_REQUEST['query'])) {  
    $query = $_REQUEST['query'];
    $url='https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/';
$key='ApiKey';
$result= $url.($query).$key;
$ch = curl_init($result);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
echo $resp;
    }
?>
```

My html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // when the user clicks the button
    $("button").click(function(){

          $.getJSON("shortner.php?query="+$('#query').attr("value"),function(json){

             $('#results').append('<p>Id : ' + json.id+ '</p>');
             $('#results').append('<p>Longurl: ' + json.longurl+ '</p>');



});


    });
});


</script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="text" value="Enter a place" id="query" /><button>Get Coordinates</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Edited :

```
<?php


    if (isset($_REQUEST['query'])) {  
    $query = $_REQUEST['query'];
    $url='https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/';
$key='Api';
$key2='?key=';

$result= $url.$query.$key2.$key;
$requestData= json_encode($result);
echo var_dump($query);
$ch = curl_init($requestData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
echo $resp;
    }
?>
```

Comment: What does echo var_dump($query) look like?

Comment: It gave this: string(70) "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698411/json-null-error-help-in-php"
I gave input url of this page.

Comment: According to the Google documentation, the URL part is supposed to be included in a JSON formatted post body (i.e. have to use json_encode on the server or something like that), if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I edited pleas look at post above.Is it right?

Comment: it looks like you json_encode the requestData twice...

Comment: I edited  It gives me a blank page

Comment: Please, mention this: http://jquery.feedables.com/story/7211447/Hotlinking-to-be-disabled-on-January-31-2011

And i think it's better to determine manually which of protocols (POST or GET) you're using to get $query: $_REQUEST['query'] could be GET or POST values either.

Don't do 'echo var_dump()' - var_dump prints its output by defaults.

Comment: and what's your var_dump(curl_error($ch)); result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked for me:

```
  <?php
   $ch = curl_init("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=MYAPIKEY&shortUrl=http://goo.gl/fbsS");

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 

   $res = curl_exec($ch);

   if (!$res)
    var_dump(curl_error($ch)); else
     echo "Yay! I've got JSON result!";

   curl_close($ch);
  ?>
```

Still there is [bit.ly](http://bit.ly/) service with similar but more powerful functions. Here is the example on how to use it (works just perfectly):

```
<?php
 if (array_key_exists("url", $_GET) && $_GET["url"] != "")
 {
  $u_name = "YOUR BIT.LY USERNAME";
  $u_apikey = "YOUR BIT.LY API KEY";

  $f = fopen("http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login=" . $u_name . "&apiKey=" . $u_apikey . "&longUrl=" . rawurlencode($_GET["url"]) . "&format=json", "r");

  header("Content-Type: application/json");

  ob_start();

  echo stream_get_contents($f);

  fclose($f);

  ob_end_flush();

  exit;
 }
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>jCarousel Examples</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("[name=send]").click(function() {
     $.getJSON("index.php?url=" + $('[name=url]').val(), function(f) {
      $('[name=res]').append('<p>Shorten: ' + f.data.url + '</p><br/ >');
     });
    });
   });
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <input type="text" name="url" size="30" />
  <input type="button" name="send" value="shorten!" />
  <br /><div name="res"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

UPD: To get your bit.ly API Key, register on the bit.ly website and go to your account (in the top) -> Settings.

Comment: Here u passed one parameter like this:  $.getJSON("index.php?url=" + $('[name=url]').val(), function(f)     How to pass two parameters so that we can read both parameters in php and work with them.I would like to pass two parameters to php like a and b which i take input from user

Comment: if you wanna pass some amount of GET arguments, use this URI form:   [file]?[arg0_name]=[arg0_value]&[arg1_name]=[arg1_value]&[arg2_name]=[arg2_value]...

E.g: index.php?moo=foo&foo=bar&ololo=zaooza

If you wanna use it in $.getJSON, you can pass JSON argument: $.getJSON('index.php', {"url":"mmooo", "moo":"foo", "foo":"bar", "ololo":"zaooza"}, function(){...}); which would be equivalent to the GET string: index.php?url=mmooo&moo=foo&foo=bar&ololo=zaooza